# How do I use golang and nuxt?

Tags: go, vue.js, nuxt.js

I want to use Golang as the server and Nuxt as the frontend, I googled it around but couldn't find any examples.

Code for express/node.js that i found out in the nuxt + express. Link is below

```
const express = require('express')

// Create express instnace
const app = express()

// Require API routes
const users = require('./routes/users')

// Import API Routes
app.use(users)

// Export the server middleware
module.exports = {
  path: '/api',
  handler: app
}
```

I can just create golang server api and deploy it as a microservice but will I lose the SSR power of nuxt? as in will google still crawl my web pages if i use a separate server as opposed to monolithic version of nuxt + node.js

link: https://github.com/nuxt-community/express-template

Regards

Answer (score 5):

You should just separate them. One server is for your backend api in golang. Other server is node server for nuxt ssr. Then you can use nginx to route requests to desired server based on path or anything.  And everything will work

Comment: can you show a basic example. I know its a lot but i really need to understand since no one have ever shown any examples before

Comment: @sinusGob i dont really understand example for what u want. You have normal nuxt setup and normal golang server. Two different servers.